# Printing objects in a 2-D array using deepToString

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a Java application that will simulate football fixtures (in the style of the World Cup) and produce match reports and results randomly. Since I want to assign players to each team, I need teams to be objects rather than just strings. This is proving problematic as I'm struggling to print the full list of teams upon running the application. So far for the Team class I have:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Team {

public static Team Team1 = new Team();
public static Team Team2 = new Team();
public static Team Team3 = new Team();
...
public static Team Team16 = new Team();

public static Team[][] FullTeamList = {
    {Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4},
    {Team5, Team6, Team7, Team8},
    {Team9, Team10, Team11, Team12},
    {Team13, Team14, Team15, Team16}
};

public static void printFullTeamList(){
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(FullTeamList));
}
}
```

(At some point I will manually change the team names, that's why I chose not to use a loop to instantiate the teams)

And the main method reads:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Team.printFullTeamList();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I run the program it returns:

```
[[Team@25d35bf2, Team@57398044, Team@141d19, Team@28825459], [Team@4187a8e0, ...
```

But if it's possible I'd like it to return:

```
[[Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, ... etc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the toString method in the Team class. More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Also, I think that Team1, ... Team16 should be placed somewhere else.

Comment: What makes you say that the teams should be placed elsewhere?

Comment: @viainvested: They are static and does not help your Team class. A Championship or something similar seems more appropriate to place the `Team`s.